# wxTreeItemId how to get data

Tags: c++, user-interface, wxwidgets

I'm tried to create my own version of the wxTreeItemId which stores extra data. Sew below:

TreeItemId.h

```
#ifndef TREE_CTRL
#define TREE_CTRL

#include "wx/treectrl.h"
#include "Particle System.h"

class TreeItemId : public wxTreeItemId
{
public:
    TreeItemId(ParticleSystem* system);
private:
    ParticleSystem* particleSystem;
};
```

TreeItemId.cpp

```
TreeItemId::TreeItemId(ParticleSystem* system) 
: wxTreeItemId()
{
    particleSystem = system;

}
```

I want to use an event to get the selected TreeItem but I can't work out a way of using my treeItem class rather than the standard.

I want to do something in the line of:

```
void TopRightPanel::OnSelChanged(wxTreeEvent& event)
{
    TreeItemId *item = (TreeItemId)event.GetItem();
}
```

This doesn't work though... Any advice would be appreciated. Do I need to use my own version of wxTreeItemData?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should subclass your data object from `wxTreeItemData` instead of `wxTreeItemId`.
Let's say you have `MyItemData : public wxTreeItemData {};` then

```
wxTreeItemId itemId = event.GetItem();
MyItemData * data = (MyItemData *)m_MyTreeCtrl->GetItemData(itemId);
if(data) { /* Doo what you need here */ }
```

In order to set the item data you need to use [InsertItem()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_tree_ctrl.html#a06e1e6b25a7121922412eea510bd3109) method and specify the data object there. Or use [SetItemData()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_tree_ctrl.html#adb74a81b41ab25bd38884311bb4b3b46) for existing item and pass item ID and data object to this method.